# Roomba hasn't run for the past two weeks and over 2800 questions evaded it

Tags: bug, status-completed, automatic-deletion

I've noticed the Roomba hasn't run for the past two weeks at around 3:00AM UTC. As per https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba an example is the following question that should have been deleted over 24 hours ago because it was closed / last modified 10 days ago:

[Reverse engineering a javascript [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73848094)

---

Generally, the fact that this issue is for real can be verified by active close voters. For that, they can get to [their close vote history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=votes&sort=closure), page through to votes cast on Sep 24-26 and check if there are clearly eligible questions. Example list of such questions picked by a particular close voter: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73849898) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73848647) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73850283) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73756120) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73845644) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73825037) [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73845762) [8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73838043) [9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73838471) [10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73841604) [11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73842040) [12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73842083) [13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73842196) [14](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73844244) [15](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73844647) [16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73845237) [17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73846157) [18](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73847367) [19](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73848346) [20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73845712) [21](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37542630) [22](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73843958) [23](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73844528).

A bit different way, available to any user at all, is to check search results for [closed:yes duplicate:no answers:0 score:-100..-2 lastactive:26d..11d](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano%20answers%3a0%20score%3a-100..-2%20lastactive%3a26d..11d). As of now this search shows **over 2800 questions** looking like they somehow evaded roomba scripts.

Actual amount of such questions is likely much higher because these are merely clear cut easy to search examples. For example, if we do less conservative (though slightly less reliable) search cut by [score 0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano%20answers%3a0%20score%3a-100..0%20lastactive%3a26d..11d) instead of -2, amount of questions raises to over 5200. And this doesn't even account for even more questions having answers, many of which would also qualify for roomba (when answers are neither accepted nor positive score).

Comment: I just checked on other sites and it ran around 30 minutes ago (3:00 AM UTC). Someone who has 10k might want to check [the moderator tools for today's deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today) if there are roomba'd questions or not.

Comment: I'd checked on EE before posting at it worked there, that's why I posted here it's probably specific to SO.

Comment: this can be a side effect of recent [introductions of Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/165773)

Comment: Some more examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73841275/11682469), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73841257/11682469), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73840833/11682469), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73840536/11682469), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73840381/11682469) etc. (you can find many more)

Comment: @gnat if that's the case, then it really saves the questions from being roomba'd...

Comment: What gnat said. I expect that the migration to Saves consumed a hefty chunk of system resources, so it's reasonable that lower priority tasks were postponed while the migration occured, and while they were scrambling to fix the problems that were noticed part way through the migration.

Comment: What's the harm in 1400 pieces of garbage being left on the side of the highway

Comment: This is a real problem, I just saw another question like this for PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159351/how-to-decode-this-file-php?noredirect=1#comment130933911_74159351

Comment: This is still going on. It's interfering with the [script] burnination, since there are several hundred items that should've been burninated but weren't.

Comment: possibly related feature request at MSE: [Make handling of links to deleted posts consistent with that of follow-post feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383179/165773) - in case if this bug is caused by problems in updates of Saves lists to reflect roomba deletions then apparently changing its way to how it is done in follow-posts would help

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Eh, burninations are a bit of an exception. I delete the backlog there regularly, including any posts that will or should have roomba'd, largely because burninations produce a large amount of posts that won't roomba, and 10k/20k delvotes are better spent elsewhere

Comment: It's great how a month has nearly passed and no official response. Not sure why I'm surprised.

Comment: @user692942 well, as pointed in [comments below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420707/roomba-hasnt-run-for-the-past-two-weeks-and-over-2800-questions-evaded-it?noredirect=1#comment930890_420942), if the fix carries risk of affecting [meta-tag:saves] they will try to delay addressing it as much as possible (if you ask me whether this looks like sort of negligence to efforts of "[.015%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343839/165773)" folks curating site content - yes, it looks exactly like this)

Comment: @gnat true, but if that is the case then just say that. Any response is better than nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for raising this. I'd passed this issue on to the devs, but it may have gotten lost among other issues. The devs are looking into this now.

Comment: The devs have confirmed that this behavior is unintentional, and we've raised an incident for this issue internally.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Sorry about the delay here folks, this one fell through our cracks for a little bit there (we're actively working with our SREs to improve our monitoring).

The issue was indeed related to the Saves release, basically part of what Roomba does is to cleanup bookmarks. After Saves was released, Roomba needed a one-time update of 4 million+ rows that it couldn't complete (exclusively Stack Overflow scale), and the jobs that ran after that cleanup were failing. This issue has been fixed.

I went ahead and manually ran Roomba a couple times to clean things up, so everything should be back to normal now (and back to normal daily cadence).

Appreciate the report, and again apologies for the delay, we know this is a critical feature to our community.

Comment: excellent, thank you! All of my checks suggest that roomba cleaned up stuff. In particular, all example questions mentioned in this bug report are now gone. One thing I'd suggest for the future is to just discard automatic removal of links to deleted posts from Saves - just like it is done in followed lists. This way Saves wouldn't interfere with roomba at all. There is really no need to "inherit" this risky complicated thing from bookmarks

Comment: I don't use the feature much, but for 10k users, does this mean that their bookmarks/saves get removed by Roomba, along with the question?

Comment: And if so, is this a desirable feature, or something that should be revisited?

Comment: At least with these last few roomba runs, I had both questions and answers in my Saves which were deleted by Community, but all posts (as far as I could tell) were still accessible in Saves. @miken32

Answer (score 22):

In the absence of any feedback from developers we can only guess what's going on. And, as time goes by this issue looks more and more like related to recent introduction of [Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/165773).

If you think of it, it is hard to imagine any other reason why it takes so much time to do what on a surface looks like simple recovery of periodic launches of a script that has been proven to work fairly smoothly for almost 10 years now. There is probably something that makes this harder than it seems and recent introduction of Saves feature looks like truly best match to that "something".

Indeed, we can understand that auto-deletion should somehow interplay with Saves feature - specifically, deleted posts should be removed from Saves lists for users under 10K (probably along with restoring in case of undeletion). And trouble integrating this new feature looks like the most plausible explanation why developers can't fix the issue for almost two weeks.

---

Another piece of this puzzle can be obtained comparing how things work at smaller sites. Thing is, at smaller sites roomba scripts seem to work as usual - this can be verified eg by running same search for [closed questions with negative score and no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano%20answers%3a0%20score%3a-100..-2%20lastactive%3a18d..11d).

Absence of complaints from smaller sites users additionally suggests that over there, auto-deletion interplays with Saves as expected. Now, one could naturally expect that things would work the same at Stack Overflow with the only difference being in scale and likely a big one - few orders of magnitude.

Successful running on smaller sites suggests that functionally roomba interplay with Saves works fine, which leads to next most likely reason for the issue being performance.

It is as if they couldn't figure how to properly "map" to Saves similar performance tuning that was made in the past for bookmarks which used to work fine with auto-deletions even at the scale of Stack Overflow.

...Or, as if they missed the trick that made [follow-posts](/questions/tagged/follow-posts) feature smoothly coexist with roomba without any performance tuning at all - I mean, simply keep deleted posts in followed lists (unless user manually removes them from their list).

Really, having links to deleted posts in Saves is not a big deal. People had such links in their flag history page for ages and nobody worried. People had these links in their follow-posts and there was no pain (except for initial minor inconvenience until users got an option to manually remove such links from their lists).

Saves can have links to deleted posts without messing with Roomba auto-deletion and this would be okay - just the same as it is okay to have such links in flag histories or in follow-posts lists.

---

Summing up, so far it looks like auto-deletion scripts are turned off at Stack Overflow because running them causes performance problems with making respective updates to Saves - either these take too much time or maybe somehow degrade site performance or something like that.

<sub>(Once again, in the absence of feedback from developers we can only guess based on what we observe.)</sub>

Comment: a side note, I think there is zero chance that they would anyhow compromise Saves in favor of Roomba. Thing is, Saves (along with, and possibly even more than [meta-tag:dark-mode] and [meta-tag:follow-posts]) make a cure for an ancient curse of Stack Overflow, when the site that was vitally important for millions professionals had its stats looking really poor compared to linkedins, twitters and facebooks out there because folks using SO had no incentive to create and maintain an account

Comment: ...for folks willing to get roomba back this is probably bad news because due to complexity and risks involved in necessary performance tuning fixing it will likely be delayed as much as possible. Unless somehow strongly pushed they will be inclined to postpone any work on that, for the fear of effort and potential of somehow breaking Saves

Comment: I doubt it's intentional, but it wouldn't surprise me if they accidentally set up saves in a way that adds <a thing> that prevents roomba from taking place like it should. A similar situation took (and is still taking) place with stuck tags, so it's not an unreasonable guess. Sadly.