# How was a new user under 10 reputation able to post an inline image?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, new-users, images

Can this be stopped now, please?

It's just getting ridiculous:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248583/type-name-expected-and-some-errors

> [image]

### Can we stop that silly experiment right now, please

I thought that users under 10 reputation couldn't post inlined images – but a user was able to do so in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199272/maximum-pairwise-product-c

> [image]

Is this a bug or a recent change in policies?

---

Update:
I've edited that question now to what I believe it normally should look like under our policies in action.

---

Another Update:
The abuse is getting worse and worse:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226802/c-program-to-display-a-cross-pattern

> [image]

I have serious doubts that such will improve questions asked via the "1st question wizard"

Comment: Yeah this is a headscratcher.  Not even a quick upvote/revert on that question could explain it, and the account is too new to have an old question that was upvoted be deleted.

Comment: My money is on wizard bugs

Comment: "created from wizard"

Comment: @KevinB well even weirder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ask Wizard for New Users Feature Test is complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416735/ask-wizard-for-new-users-feature-test-is-complete)

Comment: "_Changes since the original announcement_ [...] _Images_ [...] _In the editor, new users will be able to post images (since previously they would just end up posting links to images, which is less helpful). We will monitor this to see if this results in a degradation of quality._"

Comment: I mean, it is a bit neater to allow the image through than just the link, it's just no more correct.

Comment: @Ivar well, that was an experiment for a certain time as far I understand, is that really still in  action?

Comment: If anything seems to be _"neater"_ than just the link to accept an image upload for textual programming questions, then there should be an OCR in that wizard in 1st place to convert into code formatted markdown automatically  @KevinB

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ AFAIK the wizard that was mentioned in that post is the one that has been [graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421038/the-ask-wizard-2022-has-graduated). I don't know if they intentionally left this feature in.

Comment: @Ivar well, that question received status [tag:status-review]. Let's  see what the devs investigate

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ don't hold your breath. :( Over two weeks of status review [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420707/839601) didn't lead to anything, not even a comment like "yeah we've seen this bug report"

Comment: "*I've edited that question now to what I believe it normally should look like under our policies in action.*" I'm not aware of a policy that says we have to remove embedded images from posts of users under a certain threshold level. Seems like it's reducing the quality of the post to remove the embedded image?

Comment: @TylerH it just Shows it's _original quality_ IMO. Remember that images aren't intended to display code or otherwise plain text.

Comment: On the one hand, making it easier to post images of code seems bad.  On the other hand, we've got years of experience that shows that preventing people from inlining said images doesn't even come _close_ to stopping people from posting them anyway.  So, a wait-and-see-and-analyze-the-data approach might be reasonable here.

Comment: While I'm willing to "wait-and-evaluate" regarding images of code, one of the important things not allowing very low rep users to inline images does is prevent spammers and trolls from posting inappropriate images. On sites where the low-rep inline images restriction doesn't exist, they do periodically end up with people posting NSFW images, sometimes quite a few and sometimes quite graphic. Do we really want to subject people who are just browsing new questions to such images? Having the restriction on inline images at least made it necessary to make an active choice to fetch the image.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ regarding OCR, there was a Meta question not too long ago with a [nice answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415047/1744230) mentioning Google Lens which might have some relevancy to your comment. But I think the general consensus is that OCR is not a viable solution. *In hindsight, I think your comment was more tongue-in-cheek though, sorry if I misinterpreted :P*

Comment: Slightly related: *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)*

Comment: Another example: [Input from user in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74211894)

Comment: One more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74220349/pull-data-table-using-google-script-and-use-datatable-with-full-screen

Comment: I know that when I was a new user, people who had more reputation edited the posts with the image inline, are you sure this didn't happen?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck No, that didn't happen with these questions. Apparently the "question wizard" allows new users to do that inappropriately

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74249775/setting-up-vscode-for-c

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74270401/1.  This was disallowed long ago as per [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/3744182) by [Taryn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/taryn) to [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182).

Comment: And another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74286277/winforms-newtonsoft-unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value-c-pat

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Stacks Editor as used in the Ask Wizard now abides with the same rules and basic workflow as the regular editor when it comes to new users (< 10 rep) posting images:

- New users can upload images
- When they do so, the image will be added in markdown as a link, and not as an image
- If they try to convert the link into an image (by adding a `!` before the link), server-side validation will not allow the question to be posted, and will provide an error message letting the user know that they cannot add images to posts

Comment: The main problem we are having isn't so much new users posting explicitly inappropriate pictures (I can see how that would be a problem though), as the flood of horribly bad questions containing pictures of code. The Wizard should regard any attempt by new users to post pictures/links to pictures with great scepticism. For example I just now gave the Wizard a try, purposely writing an awful question to see what would happen. The end result after the Wizard told me to use a better title was this:

Comment: Title: "What is a certain way to find some cute cat pictures using Google?"

"My hard drive lacks cute cat pictures. I can't seem to find any on the Internet. I'm talking about pictures such as this: `<url with link to a jpg>`. 
Do you know how I can find any? By cats I mean `4-legged` furry animals with tails that say `meow`. I tried to type "cute cat pictures" in the Google search engine but nothing came up. For example: `cute cat pictures`. I expected cute cat pictures to pop up."

Tags: [tag:cat] [tag:image]

Comment: The Wizard only complained on one thing and that was my phrasing of the title, which was originally "Do you know how to find some cute cat pictures using Google?". It never complained about me linking to an off-site image containing a picture of a cat or asking a blatantly off-topic question for that matter. My main point here is that all manner of bells and whistles should go off when a new/very low rep user tries to post an URL to an image. (jpg, gif, tif etc common formats)

Comment: @Lundin the ask wizard is just a new ui setup for asking, splitting up some steps, rearranging others, more guidance, etc. It introduces no new heuristics, ML, AI (etc) for evaluating content to prevent low quality and spam. Those are great things to have, and we want to do them, but you are complaining here about the lack of something that the ask wizard never advertised itself to have.

Comment: Yeah maybe I'm confusing the wizard with general ask a question features, but regardless: it doesn't sound too difficult to have it scan the body for URLs and in case of one leading to a picture, notify the user: "When posting a picture to clarify your question, ensure that you are not posting a picture of code or text. Such questions will get a poor reception. Instead, post code or text in text format."

Answer (score 21):

> In the editor, new users will be able to post images (since previously they would just end up posting links to images, which is less helpful)...

I understand that assumption allowing this is that it will be helpful for genuine users willing to post their genuine questions through [Ask Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416735/839601).

The sad thing though is, this is also an invitation for all sorts of spammers and trolls to learn how to automate their way of dumping trash via Ask Wizard.

If (or, rather, when) they will find out, Stack Overflow will get flooded with "entertaining" graphics content - porn, animation, gigantic colorful ads etc etc. And I have a feeling that this will happen sooner (*much* sooner) than inexperienced askers will learn to abstain of posting photos and screen shots of their code.

"This is why we can't have nice things."

Comment: You're probably right about this becoming an avenue for spam abuse.  I'm sure when that happens, it will get shut off again quickly.

Comment: Meh, if we assume bad actors then I would say don’t let them post images at all. Having to click an obscure link isn’t much of a protection unless one refuses to look at any links.

Comment: "animation"????

Comment: @TheMaster if memory serves I have seen spam with animated pictures leaked through at smaller sites in the network (where new users aren't restricted). In fact all "entertaining" stuff liste here is based on my recollection of spam posts seen at smaller sites

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Personally, I agree that us only being able to force images to be posted as non-embedded links is non-ideal compared to preventing the image being uploaded at all... Is there an existing feature request on MSE or MSO regarding disabling image-uploading entirely for new users?

Comment: Bit of history, @TheMaster / V2Blast: once upon a time, new users were blocked from posting images entirely. We logged when they tried and hit the block, so when the request to soften the block came up for review I was able to pull a full record of all blocked images across all sites for a period of time, and reviewed all of them to establish risk. I saw beheading pics. I saw porn. I saw advertisements. I saw so very, very many screenshots of text editors. The one thing I didn't see much of was ...  useful, relevant images. But hey, current employees are welcome to the eyeball bleach now.

Comment: @Shog9: Yikes. Good to know...