# Multiple issues when adding images in new Ask Wizard

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-users, ask-question-wizard, stacks-editor

For about 7 years now, we've had a really useful, [sitewide feature in place that warns new users (<15 rep) when they post an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/11810933).

- Example from Ask Ubuntu (from a new-user test account I created):

  [image: Ask Ubuntu Add Image Screen]
- However, the warning appears to be missing or broken in the new Ask Wizard implemented here on SO:

  [image: Stack Overflow Add Image Screen]

The *Powered by imgur* (perhaps required by license agreement?) and *CC BY-SA* attribution information are also missing.  Likely these are the *undefined* blocks.

I was about to (politely) chastise a new user for ignoring the image warning, but then realized that I might want to confirm that it was still working after a major update like the Ask Wizard.  Turns out that was a good idea ...

I know there's a [separate post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421079/11810933) regarding the ability for new users to post inline images with the new Wizard.  This seems intentional (<strike>and probably a reasonably change, IMHO</strike>) [or not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421175/11810933) as @gnat points out), but I hope the "Warning" text can be put back in.  Whether users pay attention to it or not is another question, but at least then we can properly (and yes, politely!) correct them if they do.

Comment: Images are one of the least benefit a properly asked question needs here. They are mostly just abused by new users as demonstrated in my post. It should still be forbidden and not shown for new users. Anything else (warnings or such) won't prevent that.

Comment: And worsening more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74251817/program-for-a-sum

Comment: I never needed to follow those links to waste my time with them, a simple hover would reveal it's an image at imgur.stack, and other 3rd party links aren't allowed to present problematic code. So what?

Answer (score 11):

These have both been addressed:

- Missing imgur branding and license info in Ask Wizard (and a few other places not noted here that use the Stacks Editor): [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- An explicit warning notice to the upload pane for new users (similar to old editor) has been added for new users, works the same way it does on the old editor [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image]

> ask wizard image
> upload; two issues are reported
> both now completed

Comment: Can we use the chance and make it a pop-up banner that needs to be actively dismissed so we make it *a little* harder to ignore? My [previous suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416327/6045800) *does* have a `[status-review]` on it...

Comment: @Tomerikoo don't have time for a bigger change like that at the moment. And would want to introduce that with a test on it, to see if the thing that is more intrusive to the workflow (like a popup) makes a difference in terms of quality (since anything we add that introduces more clicks _will_ cause fewer people to fall off the asking funnel, so need to see if the tradeoff is worth it).

Comment: @YaakovEllis Thanks for your response! Will be looking out for that test announcement!