# Ask Wizard does not show the warning about images of code or errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, ask-question-wizard, stacks-editor

When a new user goes to upload an image, they're supposed to see a warning that says

> Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the above warning in the image upload flow]

While users have never been *especially* good about reading that message, it was better than nothing.  Unfortunately, it appears that this warning was never added to the new Stacks Editor.  And so, since all new users are required to use the Ask Wizard, and the Ask Wizard uses the Stacks Editor, nothing is what they get:

[image: Image of the upload flow with no warning displayed. The word "undefined" appears twice in the lower right, instead of "Powered by Imgur" and "User contributions licensed under CC BY-SA (content policy)".]

<sup>(the "undefined" instead of "Powered by Imgur" and "User contributions licensed under CC BY-SA (content policy)" when the editor is split into two boxes is a nice touch, too).</sup>

People do this *all the time*.  It is one of the most frequent reasons questions are closed, downvoted, etc.  Not warning users not to do this is probably having a substantial negative effect on new users' questions.

Can we get this put back?

Comment: sad to see JIT guidance being lost and and canned comments being added to do the same thing. not that the canned comments are bad, but I'll be glad if this gets fixed soon.

Comment: This has been completed. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425382/51) for more details.