Can we get a “don’t post code as an image” reminder in the submission form?
On Staging Ground (and on regular questions), I still see new people post code in images a lot. Obviously, the first thing that usually happens is that someone drives by, and tells the poster to put the code in text. Heck, Staging Ground even has a template saying exactly this.
I wonder if we could add a small reminder to the “upload image” dropdown discouraging them from uploading code as pictures.
Specifically, in this box:



it would be nice to have a little warning, e.g. “Please do not post screenshots of code or text. Instead, copy your code and use the code button {} to format it.”
I think this could significantly reduce the incidence of people posting code in screenshots. Note that for some cultures and communities it’s common to take screenshots to share issues - so a reminder of the local custom on SO would be useful for folks.

Or even as a popup when someone tries to CTRL+V an image into the post.

related fixed bug (for ask wizard): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/425382/11107541

Related request. I think it's worth reiterating my idea to link to the page for how to format code alongside this guidance.

I think replacing the supported file types with this reminder would be much more useful. Then add a info button to show supported types.

Supposedly this is implemented for <15 rep users (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors/307500#307500), but then <10 rep users can't even embed images (and are the ones most likely to straight-up post links to their screenshots). I can't test either of these things because posting anonymously is not allowed, and signing up disposable accounts is hard...

@Phil but it’s unclear if that intervention covers all cases - like the Ctrl+V case mentioned by another user, or maybe even staging ground.

Was more just pointing out that this isn't the first time something like this has been requested. I personally want this more than any other feature

It'd be nice if people actually cared about what warnings say :) The main reason I'd want it is because  it is a good excuse to post a link to the documentation. Which might be a person's first tangible hint that there actually is documentation, or rules. So yeah I classify this as a must have myself.
