# Is there a (secret?) plan / experiment to turn roomba off?

Tags: discussion, automatic-deletion

[This bug report](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420707/839601) about roomba scripts being broken was submitted a while ago. [Rough estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ayes%20duplicate%3ano%20answers%3a0%20score%3a-100..-2%20lastactive%3a32d..11d) suggests that amount of affected posts may fairly soon reach orders of tens of thousands (or maybe is already there because estimate is quite conservative).

Despite such a noticeable impact and score indicating rather strong community support, bug report has [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag seemingly ignored for about three weeks. Given that fixing it looks simple (for those interested, details in separate note below) it looks almost as intentional decision to have roomba off for certain period of time, or maybe even forever?

I checked recent posts at MSE and MSO and found nothing about discarding roomba so I decided to ask here - is anybody aware on any plan or experiment to turn roomba off?

---

<sub>As promised above, here's why fixing bug with roomba looks simple: it appears to be just a matter of turning back on scripts that have proven to work well for many years. Even if, as proposed in answer to the bug report, this may impact [saves](/questions/tagged/saves), the fix still looks simple - along with turning roomba back on, just turn off scripts that remove links to deleted posts from saved lists. Indeed, system doesn't remove such links from similar lists of [follow-posts](/questions/tagged/follow-posts) and sky didn't fall, so this shouldn't be a big deal for Saves either.</sub>

Comment: considering that they started addressing content discovery: I'd also argue that cluttering the site with such a mass of useless questions will have a negative impact on discoverability of the useful ones

Comment: @blackgreen I would add that deterioration of content because of broken roomba will likely additionally increase due to feedback loop - seeing more and more of inappropriate questions hanging around, more and more of new users will be tempted to think that it's okay to post like that

Comment: (for those interested in mentioned discarding of automatic removal of links to deleted posts in Saves - feature request to make it work the same as in [meta-tag:follow-posts] was submitted at MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383179/165773))

Comment: Thanks for raising this. I'd previously sent the Roomba issue over to the devs, but it may have gotten lost among other issues. The devs are looking into this now.

Comment: *sigh* Going with conspiracy theories is *rarely* helpful. At least to me, going there tends to significantly reduce the credibility of arguments. Something like this (Roomba being broken) is usually adequately explained by perfectly normal issues with development, issue tracking, allocation of resources, etc.

Comment: The devs have confirmed that this behavior is unintentional, and we've raised an incident for this issue internally.

Comment: @Makyen yeah. A week or two ago I would myself consider this sort of conspiracy... though back then it didn't even come to my mind asking about this. But as of now I think I've got enough data and evidence to post this as a straight question, without any hidden meaning. If somebody perceives this as conspiracy, I wouldn't care - arguments presented here are all plain facts, easy to verify, and concluding question follows them naturally

Comment: @gnat I don't see how. SE has consistently demonstrated their development process has *serious* problems & meta post reports getting to developers is ... non-optimal. The situation is improving. I applaud the work SE has put, and is putting, into improving, but they still have a long way to go. I don't see *anything* in what you've presented here that makes a conclusion that there's a conspiracy to not have Roomba running likely (even before the above statements by V2Blast). If the site's not *actually broken*, as in many people not being able to view pages, then things are handled in 6–8.

Comment: @Makyen sure, that was my own thinking process too. I started with same assumption as you - about some glitch in the development process - and based on that I got two versions, one that broken roomba somehow disappeared from their radars and another that they experimented with turning it off and either missed to communicate or maybe communicated too poorly for me to find out. Then I took into consideration fairly noticeable impact of this bug, visibility of the report and amount of its bumps / updates and decided that second option looks more likely

Comment: ...FWIW prior to posting the question I also considered presenting both options but dropped this idea in favor of keeping it easier to read, expecting that this won't really impact end result (of clarified mis/communication) anyway

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [Roomba hasn't run for the past two weeks and over 2800 questions evaded it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420707/roomba-hasnt-run-for-the-past-two-weeks-and-over-2800-questions-evaded-it) because the issue has been [resolved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421139) there.